# Cinemachine doesn't show in project window

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here's how my project window looks like :

[image]

I have downloaded Cinemachine package from unity asset store for smoother camera movements. Though tutorial's project window is like this:

[image]

As you can see it has Cinemachine in it. Because of this I can't use its functions. So how to toggle it?

Comment: what is your cinemachine version? are you have any error in console?

Comment: No errors in console. Cinemachine version: 2.8.4 Release

Comment: Downgrade to 2.3.9, its unity 2019 verified version. maybe fixed.

Comment: oh I have just checked the update log :D they moved it to the GameObject's Menu. though thanks a lot!